# How to know how many threads I can spin up?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using this to spin up threads that either insert or delete document from a DocumentDB collection.

It works, but I am not exactly sure how I'm supposed to know how many threads I can spin.

Sometimes, it works with `maxThreads` at 7, above that I'll quickly get the `Request rate is large` error. But sometimes, even at 3 threads I'll get the same error.

So this is obviously not very scientific.

I guess I would have to monitor how many RUs I've used after each calls and perhaps throttle the logic for a couple of miliseconds.

Any ideas ?

```
public class MultiThreadOperations<T> where T : IDocumentModel
{
    List<T> Documents = new List<T>();
    CollectionDB<T> Collection;
    OperationType OperationType;
    List<Task> AllTasks = new List<Task>();

    public MultiThreadOperations(List<T> documents, CollectionDB<T> Collection, OperationType opType)
    {
        this.Collection = Collection;
        Documents = documents;
        OperationType = opType;
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
        var maxThreads = 2;

        using (SemaphoreSlim concurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxThreads))
        {
            foreach (T doc in Documents)
            {
                concurrencySemaphore.Wait();

                var t = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        switch (OperationType)
                        {
                            case OperationType.Create:
                                await InsertDocument(doc);
                                break;
                            case OperationType.Delete:
                                await DeleteDocument(doc);
                                break;

                        }

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        concurrencySemaphore.Release();
                    }
                });

                AllTasks.Add(t);
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(AllTasks.ToArray());

        }
    }

    private async Task InsertDocument(T item)
    {
        await Collection.CreateAsync(item);
    }

    private async Task DeleteDocument(T item)
    {
        await Collection.DeleteFromId(item.Id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the following factors:

- Let's say the number of request units per single create/delete operation (RUs) is X RUs
- The latency/duration per request is N. Within the same region, this is ~5ms, but across the network, it could be RTT (round trip time) + 5ms.
- Then each thread can perform X * 1/N RUs per second
- If your collection is provisioned with T RU/s, then you need  the number of threads = T / (X * 1/N)

For example, within the same Azure region, if you had 10,000 RU/s, say each create or delete takes 5 RUs, and the network latency is 5ms. This means each thread can perform 1000/5 = 200 writes/second = 200 * 5 RU/s = 1000 RU/s. Therefore you need 10 threads to reach 10,000 RU/s.

Let's say, you're running the same test from a VM in Europe accessing an account in East US. The network lag is ~100ms. This means that each thread can perform ~10 requests/sec = 50 RU/s. Therefore, you need 200 threads to reach the same 10,000 RU/s.